Ghostscript/evince large poscript files merged into PDF but the final file is cropped
I'm merging some custom postscript files using gs
Each ps file starts with the following PS header (the dimension might change):
%PS
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 1618 1000

and each ps file looks ok in evince.
Now I want to merge all the PS files into one PDF using gs:
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=all.pdf *.ps

But in the pdf file, each page looks cropped+centered as if there was a maximum dimension for the PDF output. How can I fix this ?
Thanks.
